# Visual Studio Profiler does not show source code positions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2015, profiler

I'm trying to profile a Win32 native application which also makes use of some external DLL's which are same Win32 native build.

When I stop data collection at some point, the profiler starts generating an overview how much process time and data are collected where - but whatever it is, it always shows me "External code" in this tree.

To clarify my problem: this happens for all positions in my application, means where sources are available and which are built with debug symbols!

Any ideas what could cause this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you compile your projects with /PROFILE and /DEBUG flags?

Comment: @LicensedSlacker the profile-option was indeed missing but it does not solve the problem...still all marked as unknown frame/external code

Answer (score 0):

if you want show source code at debug or profiler mode, you must got pdb file for bins(include exe and dlls).

for "some external DLL's", may you can't get a match pdb.

for you win32 exe, you must generate pdb file for debug, you can google it.

Comment: PDBs are available, as mentioned above all code is built with debug symbols

Comment: I highly doubt they are not match.